# redirect a file contents to standard input in php

Tags: php, stdin

I have a file `abc.txt` with contents like:

```
hello
hi
good
bad
...
....
```

Now, How to redirect the contents of the file line by line to a **php script's standard input**, so that when the php script is executed, it can collect the inputs by any of these commands:

```
$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$line = fgets($f);
```

or

```
$f = fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: Can't ypu just replace `fopen('php://stdin', 'r')` by your `fopen('abc.txt', 'r'`)`?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: That would introduce a hardencoded filename in the script. I think that's what should be prevented in this case.

Comment: You could use `fopen($argv[1])` if you run `php abc.txt`. Check if `$argc == 2` or `$argc >= 2` before using `php abc.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
php yourscript.php < yourinputfile
```

should do the trick.

Comment: What about on the server, like apache or something?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: that would work on the commandline, what about if you are running it on a server?

Comment: @Mat - I guess Dhaivat is asking something out of this world. BTW, i got your point. Thnks for the answer.

Comment: @Dhaivat-i asked this question from the point of view of the command line.

Comment: well for that you'd need to know the exact server, how your script is called within that server, and how you want that redirection triggered - if it's possible at all.

Comment: @Mat How about redirecting from within PHP code i.e. when we don't have access to php execution command to use bash '<' redirect?